# Get master page name through child page using VB.net code in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On a project: [www.includehelp.com](http://www.includehelp.com/) I am using more than one master pages, and there are more than 2500 child pages, they are created by different master pages. Now my question is that, how can I get the master page's name on the child page.
I want to simply write a code behind on the child page to get the master page name and then I will further work according to the master page name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Master.GetType().Name` or `MasterPageFile`.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying and let you know :)

Comment: Master class is not accessing, is there any file to be included?

Comment: Master is a property of the Page class. Can you share your code?

Comment: Its done now, thanks you by using: 'string master_pageName = Page.MasterPageFile;'

Comment: Can you please check message on your twitter account